# Add particles on button click

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation, particles

Here I want to display [particles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PMddC.png)

Hi guys, I want to program in javascript that every time you click on the button a particle appears which then shows +1 for example.
Like in this cookie clicker (I hope you can see it):
[image: Particles on https://orteil.dashnet.org/cookieclicker/]

I already looked at particles.js, but I didn't find the right result for me there. I would like to display the particle on every click, I want it to float to the top and then disappear.

Comment: You can use tsParticles, sample here: https://codepen.io/matteobruni/pen/BaOLEqW

Answer (score 1):

I think you need something like this, I am adding one button and when clicking on it it will append +1. As per this now you can modify it according to your requirements.

```js
const addBtn = document.getElementById("add-button");
const particleBox = document.getElementById("particle-area");

function createParticle(parentElement = document.body) {
  const particle = document.createElement("div");
  particle.classList.add("particle");
  particle.innerHTML = "<h1>+1</h1>";
  if (parentElement) {
    parentElement.append(particle);
  }
  return particle;
}

addBtn.addEventListener("click", function() {
  const particle = createParticle(particleBox);
  particle.addEventListener("animationend", function() {
    particle.remove();
  });
});
```

```css
#particle-area {
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column-reverse;
}

.particle {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  animation: particle-animation 2s ease-out;
}

@keyframes particle-animation {
  0% {
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(0);
    opacity: 1;
  }

  100% {
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(1);
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="particle-area"></div>
<button id="add-button"> Mine Gold</button>
```